# Firebase cloud function doesn't work on Cordova

Tags: firebase, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a notification to every user in my Cordova app, at a schedule date automatically. I tried to create a cloud function, but the log on firebase don't show any error.

I tried to make this function, and I'm using the `cordova-plugin-firebase-lib` to receive notifications, if I go to the firebase console and send it manually it works

```
//import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

    if(valueObject.photoUrl !== null) {
      valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
    }

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.name,
            body: valueObject.text || valueObject.photoUrl,
            sound: "default"
        },
    };

  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };


    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

when i try to add name and text to message on my data base nothing happens

Comment: Hi, can you share more about what you're doing? How are you trying to add name and text to message on your database? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I did manually from the firebase database, on my database i have a collection call 'messages', and i need to send a notification whenever a new document with the field name and text is created